# Toolbar With Ic_drawer

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar

I want a material drawer with ic_drawer but what happened is that I cant display my ic_drawer although navigation drawer is working perfectly

I had  followed this [tutorial](http://www.android4devs.com/2014/12/how-to-make-material-design-navigation-drawer.html)

This is my output

[image]

I had done something like this

```
  frameLayout= (FrameLayout)findViewById (R.id.content_frame);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);



    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView); // Assigning the RecyclerView Object to the xml View

    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);                            // Letting the system know that the list objects are of fixed size

    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(TITLES,ICONS,NAME,EMAIL,PROFILE);       // Creating the Adapter of MyAdapter class(which we are going to see in a bit)
    // And passing the titles,icons,header view name, header view email,
    // and header view profile picture

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);                              // Setting the adapter to RecyclerView

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);                 // Creating a layout Manager

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);                 // Setting the layout Manager


    Drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.DrawerLayout);

          // Drawer object Assigned to the view


    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,Drawer,toolbar,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close){

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            // code here will execute once the drawer is opened( As I dont want anything happened whe drawer is
            // open I am not going to put anything here)
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            // Code here will execute once drawer is closed
        }



    }; // Drawer Toggle Object Made
    Drawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle); // Drawer Listener set to the Drawer toggle
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();               // Finally we set the drawer toggle sync State

}
```

What I want is that the material drawer should be displayed with ic_drawer

**REQUIRED OUTPUT**

[image]

This Is My **XML**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/DrawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:elevation="7dp">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar">
    </include>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World" />

</LinearLayout>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"

    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: could you paste your XML file as well? I think it has something to do with the layout xml.

Comment: This Is My XML File @ss1271 http://paste.ofcode.org/de8TEj4C5huDSTNiULVQix

Comment: please paste the XML inside your question, thx

Comment: please check my answer to see if it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DrawerLayout` using the similar way like `FrameLayout` to organise view's z-order.

So instead of this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar">
    </include>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World" />

</LinearLayout>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

put your `content_frame` before your `tool_bar`, like this:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar">
    </include>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thus, your `Toolbar` will on top of your `Drawer`

Please let me know if it works.

Comment: I'm afraid you're using the toolbar & drawer in the wrong way. The images (drawer header) you put in your toolbar should be inside the drawer. Toolbar is like action bar. You can find more info in here http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

Comment: And have you changed something else in your xml other than the part I posted in my answer?

Comment: oops sorry u r ryt ..i had put background_poly inside toolbar ..but now i have a problem i can see click on that 3 dots

Comment: bro i had one more proble..although it is solved but toolbar side my some content of onother activity

Comment: could you start a new question? as i'm getting a little bit busy ATM

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79789/discussion-between-tufan-and-ss1271).